If $(X,T)$ is first countable and $S\subset X$ then $x\in\overline{S}$ iff there is a sequence of points from $S$ that converges to $x$.
Is the following proof valid?
Suppose $X$ is a first countable space. Because $X$ is first countable, there exists a countable local basis for $x\in X$.
Let us denote this local basis by $U_1,U_2,\dots$. Now let $U_1'=U_1$ and let $U_2'=U_1'\cap U_2$ and so on letting $U_{n+1}'=U_n'\cap U_2$. As a result,
$U_1'\supset U_2'\supset\cdots$. Now if $x\in S$, clearly the sequence consisting of just $x$ converges to $x$. So suppose $x\not\in S$. Then $x$ is a limit
point of $S$, and therefore every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $S$ different from $x$. In specific, there exists $s_n\in U_n'\cap S$
such that $s\not=x$. Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of these points. To see that $\{s_n\}$ converges to $x$ consider an open subset $V$
of $X$ such that $x\in V$. Then there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_N'\subset V$. By the fact that $s_n\in U_n'$ for all $n$, $s_n\in V$ for all
$n\geq N$. Therefore $\{s_n\}$ converges to $x$.
Now suppose there is a sequence of points from $S$ that converges to $x$. Because $X$ is first countable, there exists a countable local basis for $x\in X$, call it $\{s_n\}$.
Let us denote this local basis by $U_1,U_2,\dots$. Now let $U_1'=U_1$ and let $U_2'=U_1'\cap U_2$ and so on letting $U_{n+1}'=U_n'\cap U_2$. As a result,
$U_1'\supset U_2'\supset\cdots$. Because $U_n'$ is open for all $n$, for each $U_n'$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s_m\in U_n'$ for all $m\geq N$.
That is to say there is always some $s_m\in U_n'$. If $s_m=x$ for any $m$, then $x\in S\subset \overline{S}$, so suppose $s_m\not=x$ for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
Suppose $V$ is an open subset of $X$ containing $x$. Then there exists some $l$ such that $U_l'\subset V$ and therefore there exists some $L\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$s_l\in V$ for all $l\geq L$. Therefore every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $S$ different from $x$, so $x$ is a limit point of $S$ and therefore
$x\in\overline{S}$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

First bit seems fine, you do not need to separate out the case $x \not \in S$ nor do you need a sequence that is never $x$. Second bit, the definition of closure is that $x \in \overline S$ iff each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $S$ (that is, $U \cap S \ne \emptyset$). Every open neighborhood of $x$ excludes only finitely many $x_n$s (definition of convergence), and in particular the intersection will be non-empty.
